# How to write ln(1+x) as a power series centred at 0?

Tags: calculus

I know that the derivative is $$\frac{1}{1+x}$$ and I use the geometric series to write it as

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n$$. Since it is a derivative of $$ ln(1+x)$$ I need to find an antiderivative and that is

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Is this right?

Comment: You lost a $-$ sign, it is $\sum \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n+1}$

Answer (score 1):

**Almost.** You integrate $x^n$ to get $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, so that $(-x)^n = (-1)^n x^n$ becomes $(-1)^n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, *not* $(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$. *(The minus sign does not "get integrated.")*

The resulting series is
$$
\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{n}}{n}
 $$
for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$. A simple way to check at least the first two terms:
$$
\ln(1+0) = 0
$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 1$$
so that the first two coefficients should be (and are) $0$ and $1$, respectively.

Comment: That makes sense. I completely forgot about the $$-x$$. But when I separate it into $$(-1)^n(x^n)$$ and take the antiderivative, shouldn't it be  $$(-1)^n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} $$

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison Yes. (I had originally a typo, corrected as soon as I noticed.)

Answer (score 0):

Try integrating both sides. Note that the expansion loses validity outside of the open interval $(-1, 1)$.  Use the fact that $(-x)^{n}
= (-1)^{n}x^n$. This will prevent the confusion with the sign.